# If we perform fourier transform to a pure sine wave, why it gives a bunch of frequencies?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

If you perform a fourier transform to a pure wave say 5 cycle per second you would get the dominant frequency of the wave it is made of. But not only it gives up the only frequency the wave has been made of ,it gives up a bunch of other frequencies also which are not dominant in wave.
My question is why it gives up other frequencies when the in reality the frequencies aren't there at all or is it?
Is a pure wave of 5 bit per second also made of other frequencies also ? If yes how?
Or is it just a mathematical tool not express the reality.

Comment: Which frequencies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you Fourier transform a pure sine wave you get a single component. But remember, a pure sine wave is *eternal*. I suspect that you're doing a FT to a sinusoidal signal of finite duration.

Comment: @PM2Ring ...and a finite duration is multiplication by a "box function" in the time domain which is convolution with a $sinc$ function in the frequency domain. (Which is why my personal motto is "Think outside the $sinc$").

Comment: @PM2Ring If you Fourier transform a pure sine wave, shouldn't you get two frequencies (one positive and one negative)?

Comment: @Sandejo Fair point.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't give other frequencies. If you get this computationally, maybe this is because the computer isn't actually taking the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.